# Oracle SQL FGA sys_context(‘userenv’,’current_sql’) truncated

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, audit

I want to log all statement against a specific table, using FGA and sys_context(‘userenv’,’current_sql’) I get close to what I need but it appears like current_sql is always truncated to 256 char.

I tried looking at current_sql1 to 7 but they are always empty.  Here is the code I'm using to set this up :

```
create table emp_audit
( whodidit varchar2(40)
, whenwasit timestamp
, sql_executed varchar2(4000)
, sql_executed1 varchar2(4000)
, sql_executed2 varchar2(4000)
, sql_executed3 varchar2(4000)
, sql_executed4 varchar2(4000)
, sql_executed5 varchar2(4000)
, sql_executed6 varchar2(4000)
, sql_executed7 varchar2(4000)
);

create or replace
package AUDIT_HANDLER
is
PROCEDURE HANDLE_EMP_SAL_ACCESS
( object_schema VARCHAR2
, object_name VARCHAR2
, policy_name VARCHAR2
);
end;

create or replace
package body AUDIT_HANDLER
is
PROCEDURE HANDLE_EMP_SAL_ACCESS
( object_schema VARCHAR2
, object_name VARCHAR2
, policy_name VARCHAR2
) is
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
  insert into emp_audit
  ( whodidit, whenwasit, sql_executed, SQL_EXECUTED1, SQL_EXECUTED2, SQL_EXECUTED3, SQL_EXECUTED4, SQL_EXECUTED5, SQL_EXECUTED6, SQL_EXECUTED7)
  values
  ( user, systimestamp, sys_context('userenv','current_sql'),sys_context('userenv','current_sql1'),sys_context('userenv','current_sql2'),sys_context('userenv','current_sql3'),sys_context('userenv','current_sql4'),sys_context('userenv','current_sql5'),sys_context('userenv','current_sql6'),sys_context('userenv','current_sql7'))
  ;
  commit;
end HANDLE_EMP_SAL_ACCESS;
end;


begin
  dbms_fga.add_policy
  ( object_schema=>'EPAT'
  , object_name=>'PERSON'
  , policy_name=>'PHI_ACCESS_HANDLED'
  , handler_schema => 'SBOUCHAR'
  , handler_module => 'AUDIT_HANDLER.HANDLE_EMP_SAL_ACCESS'
  );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears like you have to specify the length in the call to sys_context :

```
sys_context('userenv','current_sql',4000)
```